# Need to identify dynamic text value in selenium python

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, element

I am new to selenium webdriver python . I need to automate back end process of an e-commerce application ( order processing)

here the orders are classified to three types :

say A-type , B-type and C-type . 
After successful order completion the orders will listed in an interface .

In all listed orders, its order type will mentioned like 
"ORDER TYPE:A-type"
According to these three types certain scenarios will be executed. I need to identify this type. In a page there may be more than one  A-type/B-type/C-type orders.

here the orders will be listing one by one will all user details along with order type. please help in this.

its html tag details:
**order Type:**  A-type

Comment: Any code/HTML would help.

Comment: add HTML and the code you tried so that community can help you.